# How to deploy a spring application without a database connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My spring webapp uses PostgreSQL, only some functionality is database bound. I would like to deploy the application without the database connection being present.

Without the database the dataSource bean blows up on startup... and all subsequent requests fail as HTTP 500s as the bean creation error stops the application initializing.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    etc.
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    etc.
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    etc.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:146)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
    etc.
```

Data-source definition

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sadb" />

    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Surely this should be possible? I've done a lot of searching, but can't find anything related.

Comment: I don't know if the DB-required part and not required part in your application are clearly separated. If true, you may try to use spring profile, to define which beans shouldn't be activated when there is no DB connection. I didn't do any test on that, just an idea, so leave as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use embedded in memory database like h2 or hsqldb

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL"/>
```

or

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2"/>
```

In case if You don't want to use jdbc namespace

```
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but check if it works by marking database related beans to loaded lazily by setting lazy-init=”true”. Something like this :

```
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource" lazy-init=”true”>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**We were facing same issue in our project, we have solved by instantiating 
the bean lazily (lazy-init="true") as below:**

```
    <bean id="myProjectDataSource" 
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close" 
    lazy-init="true">
```